mamp 7.0 sequoia apache server not starting
I am trying to get MAMP 7.0 running on my Macbook Pro M2. When I start the servers MAMP throws an error saying: Apache couldn't be started
Here's what I've tried:

Uninstall Homebrew: no effect

Tried to manually start and stop apache from terminal: no effect

Unstalled MAMP and fresh install: no effect

Rebooting my machine: no effect

Tried changing the mysql server version from 8.0.35 to 5.7.44: no effect

Tried to change PHP version: no effect

Checked if the ports I'm using are in use: they weren't

Tried different port numbers: no effect

Uninstalling Mamp 7 and installing version 6.9 (apple silicon version): in the older version the servers start and localhost website is running and available


Unfortunately MAMP 6.9 doesn't have the Mysql version needed for Joomla 5.1
Any help is much appreciated because I'm out of my depth here.


I've just had this exact same issue. Click on the 'Try MAMP PRO now' button, follow the online instructions. Once I signed up for that everything worked fine.

Thank you JWCreative. That did the trick for me as well.

On the present day, MAMP is not running Apache on MacOS Sequoia. To have PHP and MySQL working by MAMP, change the web server type to Nginx.

I had a code signing issue on my Mac which caused Apache to fail.  The new Sequoia Update had installed a new LoadModule to Apache which was not "code signed".  I found the problem .so module in the apache logs by running: sudo apachectl -k start -e debug
What you want to do to fix: Open your apache2.conf config file and locate the offending LoadModule Line of code.  Then add your certificate name in quotes: eg. "Joe Smith"; after the line. Restart your apache:  sudo apachectl restart.
